# SQLite CreateTable<> Database that already exists is replaced

Tags: sqlite

Database that already exists is replaced by calling the method CreateTable <> in SQLite for Windows 8, erasing all the lines and creating a new table. How can I solve? following code to analyze:

```
using(var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
        {

            db.CreateTable<ListasEntid>();

            if (db.ExecuteScalar<int>("select count(1) from ListasEntid")==0)
            {
                db.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    db.Insert(new ListasEntid() { Nome = "Lista", Eletros = "Teste" });
                });

            }
        }
```

Comment: That looks a hair like the Qt interface to SQLite.  For that, there is a way to test if a table exists, but I don't recall what it is.  In any event, there's certain to be a way to test, so that you can skip the create.  (Or use "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" as bdares suggests.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the attention, but the problem was not specifically CreateTable method, but in the application configuration in the application properties, Debug tab, in option start the box was marked, "Unistall and then re-install my packege", erasing all files always initializing the debug.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what language you are using, but if you can execute raw SQL then you can use the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ListasEntid (nome text, eletros text);
```

This ensures that table ListasEntid exists without nuking any of your previous data.

Comment: I'm using SQLite / C # / Windows 8 App In summary of this method CreateTable <T> stating: "Executes a" create table if not exists "on the database. Also It creates any specified indexes on the columns of the table. It uses the schema automatically generated from the specified type. Later You can access this schema by calling GetMapping." I do not understand because it recreates the table, where q it already exists.